# .htaccess change image src

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I have `<img src="img/test.png">`

I want to change images src through **.htaccess** file

I want it to change  `<img src="files/image/test.png">`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

A simple redirect should do the job.

```
Redirect 301 /img/text.png http://example.com/files/image/text.png
```

It won't change the value in the HTML source, but that requires rather more then simple server configuration directives.

Answer (score 0):

using URL Redirecting

your .htaccess file would be

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ files/image/$1
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ files/image/$1
</IfModule>`

I have add this but not working

Comment: Is it getting redirected what is the url

Comment: its on my localhost i am using WAMP server

Comment: Have you enabled Rewrite_module in wamp php modules

Comment: Hello I have update to the live server but it still not working 
http://nightlionsecurity.com/image/